# Angular: HTML5 style URL is rendering with no stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I turned on HTML5 style URLs (no '#') in Angular like this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: true
});
```

And added a base tag:

```
<base href="/">
```

Now when I navigate to `http://profile.myapp.com/show/1234` it renders the page without any styles applied.

However when I use the URL with a '#' the page renders correctly. Similarly, if I disable HTML5 style URLs, the page renders correctly.

I'm using ui-router, configured with:

```
/** @ngInject */
function routerConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('showProfile', {
            url: '/show/:id',
            templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController',
            controllerAs: 'profileController'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/show/1234');
}
```

**CSS Injected via Gulp Task:**

The CSS is injected via the Gulp task [from this Yeoman Generator](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular).

```
<!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
<!-- inject:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/index.css">
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The task looks something like:

var injectFiles = gulp.src([
      path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.scss'),
      path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/app/index.scss')
    ], { read: false });

```
var injectOptions = {
  transform: function(filePath) {
    filePath = filePath.replace(conf.paths.src + '/app/', '');
    return '@import "' + filePath + '";';
  },
  starttag: '// injector',
  endtag: '// endinjector',
  addRootSlash: false
};
```

**Question:**

Why does this happen, and is there something I can do to fix it, other than not using HTML5 style URLs?

Comment: *"Why does this happen"* - because the URI for stylesheet is not correct. However, you didn't post how you include it in the page.

Comment: Ah yes - new to this kind of thing. I've added those details @dfsq. It appears to be a relative URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears to have been resolved by moving the base tag `<base href="/">` from the body into the head section.